# Can't align my image to the left

Tags: html, wordpress, css

At my wordpress theme at http://www.iam-us.nl/over-i-am-us I can't align my image to the left.
I have added those WordPress Generated Classes to the css

```
/******************************************
* Align box
******************************************/

img.centered, .aligncenter, div.aligncenter {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

img.alignright {
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 0 0 2px 7px;
    display: inline;
}

img.alignleft {
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 0 7px 2px 0;
    display: inline;
}

.alignright {
    float: right;
}

.alignleft {
    float: left;
}
```

But somehow the css is not read well. 
When I open firebug there is no class added to the picture at all.

Comment: You need to post a snippet of your HTML too.

Comment: try !important after some of your classes and see if it recognises - display: inline !important;

Comment: I have tried, but still no result. Looks like it somehow will not read my .alignleft line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your whole style.css and found that you have a bad comment here:

```
/** Coin Slider HACK by aSeptik *  14/06/2011 16.37.38 *  fix navigation button z-index */
#slider {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 950px;
    height: 350px;
    /*background-image: url('http://www.iam-us.nl/wp-content/themes/iamus/images/De-mens-op-de-juiste-plek.png');
}*/
```

you commented out the last curly brace!! }

so change it to this:

```
    height: 350px;
    /*background-image: url('http://www.iam-us.nl/wp-content/themes/iamus/images/De-mens-op-de-juiste-plek.png');*/
}
```

and that's it

Comment: My friend! I am glad you noticed! Thanks a lot. Realy appreciated!